# Python - Using a binded key to move the entry cursor in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So in a program I am coding I bind the enter key on the keyboard to a function. Within this function, the cursor should be moved to the end of the text in the entry widget. So for example if the user has 122|57 in the entry widget (| is the cursor) when enter is pressed I want this cursor to move to the end to give 12257|. My attempt at achieving this has resulted in an error. So below is the code that I am working with:

```
from tkinter import *

class Calc:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.displayentry = StringVar()
        self.display=Entry(parent, textvariable=self.displayentry)
        self.display.pack()

    def equal_input(self):
        self.display.icursor(len(self.displayentry))

root = Tk()
RunGUI=Calc(root)
root.bind('<Return>', Calc.equal_input)
root.mainloop()
```

I am getting an error when I press the enter key that says, "AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'display'"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `bind()` the event within the application itself. Also, the `StringVar` object has no length - you need to `get()` its contents first.

```
from tkinter import *

class Calc:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.displayentry = StringVar()
        self.display=Entry(parent, textvariable=self.displayentry)
        self.display.pack()
        parent.bind('<Return>', self.equal_input)

    def equal_input(self, event):
        self.display.icursor(len(self.displayentry.get()))

root = Tk()
RunGUI=Calc(root)
root.mainloop()
```

However, I'd recommend changing your `equal_input()` function to do the following instead:

```
def equal_input(self, event):
    self.display.icursor(END)
```

`END` is `tkinter`'s canonical way of referring to the end. It's a variable within `tkinter` that points to the string `'end'` (so you can use `'end'` instead if you feel like it).

[Here is some more info on the `Entry` widget.](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Comment: What's actually wrong about binding from outside the class (apart from that he should use `RunGUI.equal_input` instead of `Calc.equal_input`)?

Comment: @fhdrsdg - Interesting. I'd never seen it done that way but it works. I can't figure out how to bind an event to a specific widget in the `Calc` instance in that way, though. How is that done?

Comment: Well, `RunGUI` is just an instance of `Calc`, so through `RunGUI` you can access anything that's in `self` of `Calc`. To bind only to the entry widget of this specific `Calc` instance, you can simply use `RunGUI.display.bind('<Return>', RunGUI.equal_input)`. However, if you create another instance of `Calc`, it will not have this binding unless you specifically add it too.

Comment: I was trying to bind it to `displayentry` instead of `display`, not noticing that `displayentry` wasn't an `Entry` at all... -_- Anyway, I guess either is fine. I just prefer doing the binding inside the class (also makes it easier to modify bindings during runtime, as far as I can tell).

Comment: Yeah, I think the biggest difference is that binding inside the class (or at least inside `__init__`) applies to all class instances, while binding after a class instance is created only binds to that specific instance. You could of course also do the binding in a separate class method, which you only call for the instances for which you want the binding, to still do binding from inside the class but only for specific instances. The possibilities are endless ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well - why are you using len? You use icursor like this:

```
self.display.icursor('end')
```

also... this is how I bind my stuff....

```
list_of_entrys = [entry_1, entry2]

for entry in list_of_entrys:
    entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event: self.something(event.widget))
```

(The event.widget part says where the click came from)

...

Additionally, if you wanted to you could bind to `<Key>` (all key presses) - or if it's an onscreen keyboard just add `self.display.icursor('end')` to the thing that prints the keys...

*The user pressed any key. The key is provided in the char member of the event object passed to the callback (this is an empty string for special keys).*